# MySQL Inner Join Get Last Item of Joined Table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

There are two tables:

Table name: **ticket**

```
+-------+---------+---------+-------------------+
|  id   |  title       |  closed    | param     |
+-------+--------------+------------+-----------+
| 1     | test1        | 0          | 1         |
| 2     | test2        | 1          | 1         |
| 3     | test3        | 0          | 1         |
```

Table name: **ticket_event**

```
+-------+---------+---------+-----------------+
|  id   |  ticket_id   |  event   | date      |
+-------+--------------+----------+-----------+
| 1     | 1            | OPENED   |           |
| 2     | 1            | CLOSED   |           |
| 3     | 2            | OPENED   |           |
+-------+--------------+----------+-----------+
```

I need to get the last record of **ticket_event** for each ticket. Result should be:

```
test1 CLOSED
test2 OPENED
test3 NULL
```

I tried this code but I get all records for **ticket_event**:

```
SELECT t1.title as t1Title, t2.event as t2Event FROM ticket t1 LEFT JOIN ticket_event t2 ON t1.id = t2.ticket_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join `ticket` to a query that returns the last event::

```
SELECT t.title, e.event
FROM ticket t LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT e.* from ticket_event e
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM ticket_event 
    WHERE ticket_id = e.ticket_id AND id > e.id
  )
) e 
ON t.id = e.ticket_id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c4dXhrtTcyuUeUPa4LWABv/3).
Results:

```
| title | event  |
| ----- | ------ |
| test1 | CLOSED |
| test2 | OPENED |
| test3 |        |
```

Comment: what if there is an ASSIGN event? It will choose ASSIGN (considered less than CLOSED) But again we need to get CLOSED. How can I solve? Thanks

Comment: You did not mention this. So if there is ASSIGN and OPENED which one would be the result?

Comment: Always it should be the last one. I tried to explain at question title (MySQL Inner Join Get Last Item of Joined Table) But I could examplify.

Comment: The last by id or by date?

Comment: The last by id.

Answer (score 1):

A correlated subquery can do the trick:

```
select 
    t.title,
    (
        select te.event 
        from ticket_event te 
        where te.ticket_id = t.id 
        order by te.id desc 
        limit 1
    ) last_event
from ticket t
```

It is quite unclear which column in `ticket_event` you want to use for ordering. Using `date` would make sense, but that column is empty in your table, so I went for `id`. You can change that according to your real requirement.